# How to auto add a leading zero to a digit in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

i have a text box to enter a certain digit , if the entered number is a one digit number i want a leading zero to be added automatically.How could I do this? whats the code for this ?

Please help

Comment: what about this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thx for the reply ,didnt work though. is there more easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
If TextBox1.Text.Length = 1
   TextBox1.Text = "0" + TextBox1.Text
End if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Validating` event to be sure that your code will always fire. And use the `x2` format to specify that you need 2 digit number.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        TextBox1.Text = CInt(TextBox1.Text).ToString("x2")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and it should also have the text start from the end of the textbox.

```
  Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text.Length = 1 Then
        TextBox1.Text = "0" + TextBox1.Text
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength + 1
    End If
End Sub
```